# Embedding an Image Object Inside a Button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I currently have an example that embeds an image object inside of a button.
the xaml looks like this:

```
<Button Height="194" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Margin="23,27,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="216"
    Click="button1_Click">
    <Image Name="image1" Stretch="Fill"
        Source="/WPFButtonEmbedded;component/BenderInSpaceFace.png" 
        Height="105" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="158"  />
</Button>
```

However, when I try to recreate this myself i seem to get an error. I though that maybe they were binded togeather but looking at the example it doesnt seem that way.
Also the "image1" is an image that i added by clicking add exising item.

Any comments or suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: are you trying to set image as Button Background ?

Comment: What error are you getting..? Have you tried setting the build action property of the image to resource ?

Comment: no just embed the image object inside of it. The image object can be resized like it normally can but its actually embedded when ran. Its hard to explain in words but when you run it it looks like its just a picture ontop but its apart of the button

Comment: @biju build action property? Ive been trying stuff with the content property of the button

Comment: @biju -- i'll post error

Comment: ok i actually got rid of the error by deleting content"button" but when i put my image object inside of the button tag it disapers (its still in the xaml just not visible in the view)

Comment: I also tried sending the button object to back incase it was behind it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you need to set image as Content
you can do it by setting style in resource

```
<Window.Resources>
   <Image x:Key="Img" Source="/WPFButtonEmbedded;component/BenderInSpaceFace.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
   <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
      <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource Img}" />
   </Style>
 </Window.Resources>
```

then you can set the Style of the Button

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" />
```